# How can I add item in a list

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using *spring-mvc* and *thymeleaf* to create a form.

I would like to create a registration form with the attribute of a **product list**. To do this, since the user can add as many products as he wants (at least one), I therefore initialized the form with an object, and added a button so that he can use it to add a another product when he wants to.

Here is the form

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible to do that each time the user clicks on the button **Ajouter une ligne**, that we call a function of the controller which will add an empty object so that the user can fill it.

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to call the server every time you want to add a line.
The best way is doing that with JS and at the end you send a list of product to your server.

Comment: as @AyoubMkharbach said, it is best practice to add object using JS, add onclick event , when clicked a function is called which will add an object to HtmlElement, and then the same can be pass to list of objects to controller and further it can be processed in service class.